# Appending in the middle of a src attribute of Image in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a bit of code which I want to add just the letters "mb" at the beginning of the name of my image file using JQuery. This is quite green to me so I ask for your forgivness of my naivety in advabce. An example of what I am seeking to do is switching my image name from "images/folder/photo.jpg" to "images/folder/mb_photo.jpg". The images I plan to use already in classes so I have the mock up for selecting those classes already layed out. I am just stuck on how to insert in the middle of the image tag.

As requested, what I have so far is:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){     

         if ($('#content').width() < 700 ){

                      $('#photos_member').;
          $('#photos_group').;
         }

     });
```

Thank you guys in advance for your help.

Comment: Posting what you have would help.

Comment: can't you rename that image?

Comment: @ToddMotto I updated my question with what I have.

Comment: @Mr_Green It would be a difficult process to find the new image due to the use of php code that was in place before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you need...

```
function updateImageSrc(add) {
    if (add === true) {
        $("img.photos_member:not(.src-modified), img.photos_group:not(.src-modified)")
            .attr("src", function() {
                var split = this.src.split("/");
                split[split.length - 1] = "mb_" + split[split.length - 1];
                return split.join("/");
            })
            .addClass("src-modified");
    }
    else {
        $("img.photos_member.src-modified, img.photos_group.src-modified")
            .attr("src", function() {
                var split = this.src.split("/");
                split[split.length - 1] = split[split.length - 1].substr(3);
                return split.join("/");
            })
            .removeClass("src-modified");
    }
}
```

And to call it in a window resize handler, do this...

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($("#content").width() < 700) {
        updateImageSrc(true);
    }
    else {
        updateImageSrc(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is what I have... $(window).resize(function(){     

       if ($('#content').width() < 700 ){

  $("img.photos_member").attr("src", function() {
   var split = this.src.split("/");
   split[split.length - 1] = "mb_" + split[split.length - 1];
   return split.join("/");
  });
   $("img.photos_group").attr("src", function() {
  var split = this.src.split("/");
  split[split.length - 1] = "mb_" + split[split.length - 1];
  return split.join("/");
 }); 

       }

});

Comment: Should this be able to run outside of document.ready? My object is to have this happen everytime the window is resized

Comment: I'll modify it to take that into consideration.

Comment: also I was thinking about an else statement that removes the mb_ when the screen returns to normal size

Comment: That will cover both those scenarios now :)

Answer (score 1):

use like

```
<img id="test" src="images/folder/photo.jpg"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="change src"/>

$("#btn").click(function(){
var newSrc=$("#test").attr("src").split("/");
newSrc[newSrc.length-1]="mb_"+newSrc[newSrc.length-1];

$("#test").attr("src",newSrc.join());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xb5AP/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace` method.

```
var img = "images/folder/photo.jpg";

var newImg = img.replace(/\/(\w+.jpg)/, "/mb_$1");
```

`newImg` would contain the updated filename("images/folder/mb_photo.jpg")